About Chern classes via Atiyah class
I am trying to understand a construction of the Chern classes of a vector bundle $\mathcal{E}$ via the Atiyah class, like is done in this text and here in section 1.4. I am interested in the case where the base field has characteristic p>0, and I would like to know if there is a splitting lemma, as in the Chow case, for these Chern-Hodge classes. In relation to this, my question is: given a flat map $f\colon Y \longrightarrow X$, is the induced map $f^{*}\colon H^{*}(X,\Omega_{X}^{*}) \longrightarrow H^{*}(Y,\Omega_{Y}^{*})$ injective? I appreciate any references about this, in particular, for the case: $Y = \mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E}^{*})$

Read up on Frobenius maps.

Oh, ok thanks! I think that the formulation was not good. I think you mean that we can take $X = Y$ (regular) and f the absolute Frobenius, because it is flat (Kunz) and df^p = 0 for every function... In the first step of the construction of the splitting, I need to show that the pullback map to $Y =\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E}^{*})$ is injective. Is that true?
